# Using JQuery to select the Last Select Value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following html code:

```
<div id="casesList1" class="cases">
   <select id="casesList">
      <option value="1">case1</option>
      <option value="2">case2</option>
      <option value="3">case3</option>
   </select>

   <div id="casesList2" class="cases">
      <select id="casesList">
         <option value="4">case4</option>
         <option value="5">case5</option>
      </select>
   </div>

</div>
```

and I need to select using JQuery the last value of the select inputs, in the inside div.. For example, if I selected 'case5', the function should return 5, the problem is that I have more than a select input with the id 'casesList'.
I tried this:

```
$('#casesList:last option:selected').attr('value');
```

But it only selects the first select value...

Comment: You cannot use the same id twice. Change the id "casesList" to class "casesList" and try the selector ".casesList:last option:selected"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
$('select[name=category]').last().attr('value');
```

after giving the select the name category..

Answer (score 6):

For starters, you can't duplicate IDs within your page - It is invalid code. So your id of "caseList" needs to be different for each select element.

You can use duplicate classes though, so you can access each element that way:

```
$('.caseList:last').val();
```

Comment: It didn't work, but I gave it a name 'category' and this is how I solved it:
$('select[name=category]').last().attr('value');

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('.cases:last option:selected').val();
```

or

```
$('div[id^="casesList"]:last option:selected').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

element ID's should be unique, if you want to have duplicates you should use classes instead.

```
$('.cases:last option:selected').attr('value');
```

or

```
$('.cases:last option:selected').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('div.cases:last > select option:selected')[0].attr('value')
```